# Is there a pywinauto equivalent to automate the GUI from Python?

Tags: software-recommendation, python

[pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) is a set of python modules to automate the Microsoft Windows GUI. At it’s simplest it allows you to send mouse and keyboard actions to windows dialogs and controls.

Is there a linux equivalent of this python module?

thanks!

Comment: You will be able to write your own back-end for pywinauto soon.

Answer (score 4):

The [linux desktop testing project (ldtp)](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/) should offer what you need. With the [python-ldtp](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ldtp) [image: Install python-ldtp] package, you can write scripts in python. The project uses the accessibility methods to perform actions, so the application in question has to be a “standard” GTK/QT/… application and you need to enable accessibility (“Assistive technologies”).

```
sudo apt-get install python-ldtp
```

The following python script would click the “New” button in an (already existing) gedit window and enter the string `foo`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ldtp import *
from ldtputils import *
click('*-gedit', 'btnNew') 
generatekeyevent('foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sikuli (now named SikuliX)

**URL:** [www.sikuli.org](http://www.sikuli.org/)

According to the website:

> SikuliX automates anything you see on the screen of your desktop
> computer running Windows, Mac or some Linux/Unix. It uses image
> recognition powered by OpenCV to identify and control GUI components.
> This is handy in cases when there is no easy access to a GUI's
> internals or the source code of the application or web page you want
> to act on.
>
> SikuliX supports as scripting languages:
>
> - Python language level 2.7 (supported by Jython)
> - Ruby language level 1.9 and 2.0 (supported by JRuby)
>
> … and you can use it in Java programming and
> programming/scripting with any Java aware programming/scripting
> language (Jython, JRuby, Scala, Clojure, …).
>
> Though SikuliX is currently not available on any mobile device, it can
> be used with the respective emulators on a desktop computer or based
> on VNC solutions.

Please bare in mind that it's in beta.